# Docker Desktop does not start (Mac Big Sur)

Tags: macos, docker

When opening Docker Desktop (2.3.0.5), newly installed, it shows the error: 'Failed to analyse', 'The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.'

[Docker error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9YKu.png)

Running macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 with M1 chip. (Note that the newer version, v2.4 and v2.5, give different issues, upon which I was advised to install 2.3.0.5)

Answer (score 2):

The M1 chip is not currently supported. You can [track the issue on the docker roadmap](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/142).

Comment: I have exactly this error on 2.3.0.5 with Big Sur and I'm using an Intel I9

Comment: The Intel I9 is not the M1 chip.

Comment: My point was that since this occurs on intel as well, I don't think that the M1 chip is necessarily the culprit.

Comment: Quite a few errors can be triggered by multiple things. At the time of the post, there's no need to debug it on the M1 since the M1 implementation of D4M didn't exist yet. For debugging on a supported platform, that would be a different question, but the error message itself is unlikely to be sufficient to debug.